# problem about nilpotent leibniz algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

I want to prove this statement

if $A$ is nilpotent leibniz algebra then $ H \subsetneq N_A(H)$.
$H$  is a subalgebra of $A$
Can you help me how to show this.thanks

Comment: Is $N_A(H)$ supposed to be the (right resp. left) normalizer ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde;yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows from Engel's theorem for Leibniz algebras, in the same way as it follows for nilpotent Lie algebras. The proof is given in the paper [On some basic properties of Leibniz algebras](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.3345) by V.V. Gorbatsevich; here Engel's theorem for Leibniz algebras is Proposition $2$; and the corollaries show that a proper $H$ is strictly contained in both right and left normalizers.

Edit: The proof of the first corollary to proposition $2$ seems to be not convincing, see the comments below. Perhaps I should not delete this post, although it has downvotes, so that other people can see it. Please refer to YCor's proof.

Comment: I don't understand the proof of the corollary in the linked paper: I don't see how we get a left action on $L/M$ as $M$ is not a left ideal

Comment: We can act by left multiplication on the coset space ? Also for Lie algebras, $M$ is only a subalgebra of $L$, and not an ideal. Perhaps there is some unfortunate formulation here. Anyway, you have given another proof here.

Comment: It's not just an unfortunate formulation: I have no idea how to modify this to into a correct proof.

Answer (score 1):

The result is false if $H=A$ so I assume $H\neq A$. Here is a proof, which works in an arbitrary nilpotent algebra $A$, that every proper subalgebra $H$ is strictly contained in its 2-sided normalizer $N(H)=\{v:vH\cup Hv\subset H\}$. (Under this generality $N(H)$ is not necessarily a subalgebra; it's contained in the left normalizer, which, in the Leibniz case, is a subalgebra).

Define $Z(A)$ as the nilcenter of $A$ (those $x$ such that $xy=yx=0$ for all $y$, I don't know if there's a standard name). This is a 2-sided ideal.

Iterating $Z(\cdot)$, we define the ascending (nil)central series of $A$ as usual: $0=A_0\subset A_1\subset\dots$, where $A_{i+1}/A_i$ is by definition the nilcenter of $H/A_i$. Nilpotent means that $A_i=A$ for large enough $i$.

Since $H\neq A$, there exists $i$, which we choose minimal, such that $H$ contains $A_i$ but not $A_{i+1}$. So by definition, $A_{i+1}A$ and $AA_{i+1}$ are both contained in $A_i$, and hence in $H$. So if $N=A_{i+1}+H$, then $N$ is a subalgebra and $NH\cup HN\subset H$. By choice of $i$, $H$ is properly contained in $N$.